# Show current play speed in after effects

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-expressions

Is it possible to display the current play speed (eg. X2, X3.5, etc) in a text layer above my footage? 
Some of my composition layers plays at normal (X1) speed but others were time remapped or time stretched.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with expressions on the time remapped layers: create an empty text layer <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd><kbd>alt/opt</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>. Alt-click the **Source Text** stopwatch, and use an expression like:

```
var s = thisComp.layer("some layer").timeRemap.speed;
"X" + Math.round(s * 10)/10 //limits the result to one decimal place
```

The time-stretched layers are more tricky. The stretch property isn't accessible to expressions, but what you can do is use the sourceTime() function. This gets the time of the source footage. If your layers start at the beginning of the source then this expression would work:

```
var s = thisComp.layer("some layer").sourceTime()/time;
"X" + Math.round(s * 10)/10 //limits the result to one decimal place
```

if the layer source doesn't start at the beginning of the comp then you'd have to do some extra maths, like subtracting the in-point, or to make it easier you could pre-comp the source layer with the text overlay and make sure the precomp has the source footage starting at the beginning of the comp.